# how to get dump of mongodb in golang and restore it

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am using MongoDB as database and mgo and mogo libraries in Go. I want to get a dump of my DB and restore it to write some utility methods to write unit test. my purpose is to dump the database then test my functions and after all restore it. Can you help me how can I do it using mogo or mgo?

Comment: you can use mock libraries. If you wants to create test cases without touching actual database

Comment: You can make a copy of database but keep in mind, it's very expensive operation. see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/kubedb/cli/blob/master/docs/guides/mongodb/quickstart/quickstart.md

Answer (score 0):

There are mock libraries available which can be used to mock databases when creating test cases to check the database.No needs to dump database and run test cases on that. And then Restore to get your original data. Try this [library](https://github.com/cfsalguero/test_mongo_mock)

It is installing some packages for mongo db mock test cases